# Getting Hotplug react when plugging 3G netstick (with mdev)

Tags: usb, embedded-linux, 3g, cd-rom, usb-modeswitch

I'm trying to get a device running embedded linux V-2.6.31 to automatically recognize when a Huawei 3G usb stick is plugged to it, run usb_modeswitch, and communicate with the module.
it seems that usb_modeswitch doesn't work well in a system that has mdev, since the path /dev/bus/usb is only being created with udev.
I found a script that create this path and enable usb_modeswitch to work properly.
now, all i need is automation of this process, e.g., when plugging the 3G module, hotplug will first call my script, and then usb_modeswitch.
the problem is that when plugging the 3G module nothing happens when the enumeration is done (the hotplug wont run), see trace:

```
[83175.520000] usb 2-1: new full speed USB device using bcm5892-ohci:PORT-2 and address 3
[83175.730000] usb 2-1: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[83175.750000] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1f1c
[83175.760000] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[83175.770000] usb 2-1: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[83175.770000] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Vodafone(Huawei)
[83175.780000] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
[83175.800000] usb 2-1: configuration #1 chosen from 2 choices
[83175.870000] scsi1 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[83180.910000] scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
```

I'm not sure what is wrong, is there something i didn't enable? is there a KO that i need to load in order for it to work?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the content of your `/proc/sys/kernel/hotplug`?  Does it point to some script or executable or empty?

Comment: thanks for the help.
I've actually figured it out, the MOD_SR was not enabled.
once I've enabled it, and loaded the mod_sr.ko, the hotplug recognized that a "cd-rom" was plugged in.